# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ... ClassLoader.php

Tags: javascript, phpmyadmin, xampp

i cannot access PhpMyAdmin in xampp because im getting this errror:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 354

i changed all the execution time in all the files suggested here in stackoverflow but no success! i also tried reinstalling xampp and nothing.

this is what shows line 354

if (file_exists($file = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr($logicalPathPsr4, $length))) {
                            return $file;

please help!

Comment: When does this error occur; when you're first trying to connect to phpMyAdmin? Are you able to see the login page or initial/main page at all?

Answer (score 0):

go to "C:\xampp\php\php.ini" and change "max_execution_time=30" to "max_execution_time=-1" "max_input_time=60" for "max_input_time=-1". Now save the file, stop apache service and start it again

Comment: are u sure that u modify the correct php.ini? try check in your page with a "phpinfo()"

Comment: And try add "ini_set('max_input_time', '-1');" on the top of your code